# How to create a 4 dimensional numpy array from a 3 dimensional numpy array filling with zeros?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, dimensional-modeling

## The problem

Create a higher dimensional NumPy array with zeros on the new dimensions

### Details

Analyzing the last dimension, the result is similar to this:

(not an actual code, just a didactic example)

```
a.shape = (100,2,10) 
a[0,0,0]=1
a[0,0,1]=2  
...
a[0,0,9]=10

b.shape = (100,2,10,10)
b[0,0,0,:]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
b[0,0,1,:]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1] 
b[0,0,2,:]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1]
...
b[0,0,2,:]=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] 
    
a -> b
```

The objective is to transform from `a` into `b`. The problem is that is not only filled with zeros but has a sequential composition with the original array.

### Simpler problem for better understanding

Another way to visualize is using lower-dimensional arrays:

We have this:

```
a = [1,2]
```

And I want this:

```
b = [[0,1],[2,1]]
```

Using NumPy array and avoiding long for loops.

### 2d to 3d case

We have this:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

And I want this:

```
b[0] = [[0,0,1],[0,2,1],[3,2,1]]
b[1] = [[0,0,4],[0,5,4],[6,5,4]]
b[2] = [[0,0,7],[0,8,7],[9,8,7]]
```

I feel that for the 4-dimensional problem only one for loop with 10 iterations is enough.

Comment: The last two axes of `b` are a squat array and you can achieve your result with a triangular matrix. When you say `a = [1, 2]`, do you mean that you want each row of `b` to count down from each element of `a` down to 0 and then remain 0 for any leftover elements in the row? Is that 1-2 sequential? Could you have `a = [1, 3, 2]`?

Comment: I need to retain the sequence. I can have `a=[1,3,2]` but  than we would have `b = [[0,0,1],[0,1,3],[1,3,2]]`. I don't see how to do with a triangular matrix. What I was trying is to append and delete elements and add to a new np.zeros array with more dimensions.

Comment: In the first example the numbers appear in reverse order, i.e., for [1, 2, 3..., 10], you get [1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 1], etc. But in your second example they appear in forward order, i.e., that would be [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]. Which one do you want?

Comment: Both work for me but I prefer the reverse order. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your example is only concerned with a[0,0]. Do you want a similar thing to happen for each index in the first two axes of your example, or just the specific ones?

Comment: I want the same thing on each index as explained for the 2-dimensional case on the comment of the other question.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting important information in comments people may not see. This should go straight into your question body. And consider adding the expected outcome for more than just a[0,0] so we make sure we get your desired pattern right.

Comment: Just edited the question with important information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in the framework of `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

# create transformation tensors
N = a.shape[-1]
sigma1 = np.zeros((N,N,N))
sigma2 = np.zeros((N,N,N))
E = np.ones((N,N))
for i in range(N):
   sigma1[...,i] = np.diag(np.diag(E,N-1-i),N-1-i)
   sigma2[N-1-i,N-1-i:,i] = 1

b1 = np.tensordot(a, sigma1, axes=([-1],[0]))
b2 = np.tensordot(a, sigma2, axes=([-1],[0]))
```

where `sigma1`, `sigma2` are the transformation tensors for which you can transform the data associated with the last dimension of `a` as you want (the two versions you mentioned in your question and comments). Here the loop is only used to create the transformation tensor.

For `a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`, the first algorithm gives:

> [[[0. 0. 1.]   [0. 1. 2.]   [1. 2. 3.]]
> [[0. 0. 4.]   [0. 4. 5.]   [4. 5. 6.]]
> [[0. 0. 7.]   [0. 7. 8.]   [7. 8. 9.]]]

and the last algorithm gives:

> [[[0. 0. 1.]  [0. 2. 1.]   [3. 2. 1.]]  [[0. 0. 4.]  [0. 5. 4.]  [6. 5. 4.]]  [[0. 0. 7.]   [0. 8. 7.]   [9. 8. 7.]]]

**Try to avoid lists and loops when using `numpy` as they slow down the execution speed.**

Comment: This works for the arrays with one dimension but not for the 2-dimensional case and greater. For example if I have the `a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])` I would expect the result array  `b[0] = array([[[0., 0., 1.],[0., 1., 2.],[1., 2., 3.]]`, `b[1] = array([[[0., 0., 1.],[0., 1., 2.],[1., 2., 3.]]`. I tested the code and the result is `b[1] = array([[2., 3., 1.],[3., 1., 2.],[1., 2., 3.]])`.

Comment: Please precise your algorithm. Now, you would expect that `b[0]==b[1]`.

Comment: It is not `b[0]==b[1] ` for every scenario only for `a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`. For the case where `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` , `b[0] = [[0,0,1],[0,1,2],[1,2,3]]`, `b[1] = [[0,0,4],[0,4,5],[4,5,6]]`.

Comment: Again, if I understand your algorithm correctly, please try the corrected code in my answer. I introduced tensor to transform your last dimension data.

Comment: Did you check current version of the code with tensor product in my answer? That's what you need?

Comment: I checked for more dimensions and it works as I wanted. Check my solution too, I think it also works but not so optimized.

Comment: You can check your and mine solutions by measuring the runtime, especially for large sizes. Don't use lists with `numpy`. Also there is a stack function in `numpy` module (you can try it).

Comment: I will and add the results here. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry I missed that you were using the `stack` function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem but there is probably a more efficient way to do it:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) #two  dim case

a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]])# three dim case

def increase_dim(arr):
    stack_list = []
    stack_list.append(arr)
    for i in range(1,arr.shape[-1]):
       stack_list.append(np.delete(np.delete(np.append(np.zeros(arr.shape),arr,axis=-1),np.s_[-i:],axis = len(arr.shape)-1),np.s_[:arr.shape[-1]-i],axis = -1))    
    return np.stack(stack_list,axis = -1)

b = increase_dim(b)
```

I hope this can help the question understanding.

Comment: Why did you swap `a` and `b` in this explanation?